Hibernate 6.5.2.Final graalvm errors
I am working on JDA, Hibernate, HikariCP, and Korean streaming platform Chzzk.
Using Hibernate 6.5.2.Final / Hibernate-graalvm 6.5.2.Final.
While working, the following error occurs during execution after Graalvm Native Image build.
The error BytecodeProviderImpl could not be instantiated keeps occurring.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.bytecode.spi.BytecodeProvider: Provider org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl could not be instantiated
    at java.base@22.0.1/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)

To solve this error, I googled and searched for many solutions, but most of the time I found only information related to Spring.
Gradle settings are as follows.
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.5.2.Final")
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-hikaricp:6.5.2.Final")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy
    implementation("net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.14.17")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-graalvm
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-graalvm:6.5.2.Final")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP
    implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.1.0")
}

I hope for your help.

This may help.
